# qsort, compare to middle value, why cannot be equal?

Tags: c, qsort

One way of qsort implementation like follow:

```
void quick_sort(int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int p=a[n / 2];
    int *l = a;
    int *r = a + n - 1;
    while (l <= r){
        if (*l <=  p) {  // *l < p WORK WELL, BUT LIKE THIS *l <= p CANNOT GET IT .
            l++;
            continue;
        }
        if (*r > p) {
            r--;
            continue;
        }
        int t = *l;
        *l++ = *r;
        *r-- = t;
    }
    quick_sort(a, r - a + 1);
    quick_sort(l, a + n -l);
}
```

It seems that, if `(*l < p)` condition will swap both left and right when the value equal to `p`
However, just make the condition equal to `p`, so it will ignore the value that equal.
Why should `*l` cannot be equal to `p` ?

Comment: Consider the case of the same value of all elements.

Comment: can you upload the whole code.

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/162101/ This my whole code

Comment: Segfault errror, try using valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

As @BLUEPIXY hints: "Consider the case of the same value of all elements."

The following will simply increase `l` until it is just past `r`.  The while loop will exit *without* changing `r`.

```
while (l <= r){
  if (*l <=  p) {  // *l < p WORK WELL, BUT LIKE THIS *l <= p CANNOT GET IT .
    l++;
    continue;
  }
...
}
```

Then the following is called, which is the same as the parent call of `quick_sort(a, n)` - an infinite recursion.

```
// int *r = a + n - 1;  
// r - a + 1 is the same as (a + n - 1) - a + 1 the same as n
quick_sort(a, r - a + 1);
```

Comment: Hi, chux, if `(*l > p)`,the while loop will change `r`. right ?

Comment: Re; "Why should *l cannot be equal to p ?", then `*l > p` is false.  If you are posing another question "if (*l > p),the while loop will change r? "  I believe so.